# ¿Cómo calcular un cuartil bajo ciertas condiciones en R?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

explicaré lo que intento hacer:

Necesito obtener el cuartil inferior (percentil 25) de la variable **PU**, sin embargo ese cuartil debe ser construido a partir de todos los valores de la variable **Codigo** que sean iguales a **A11**

```
Nombre          Estado  Codigo    PU
   <chr>           <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
 1 independiente1  Tercero A12       30
 2 independiente2  Tercero A11       20
 3 independiente3  Tercero A12       18
 4 independiente4  Tercero A11       16
 5 independiente5  Tercero A12       44
 6 independiente6  Tercero A11       30
 7 independiente7  Tercero A12       23
 8 independiente8  Tercero A11       45
 9 independiente9  Tercero A12       23
10 independiente10 Tercero A11       19
```

Estoy aprendiendo R, agradezco todo tipo de sugerencias, ya que he buscado como aplicar dichas condiciones sin éxito alguno.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de resolverlo utilizando tidyverse es:

```
df = df %>%
  group_by(Codigo) %>%
  mutate(per25 = ifelse(Codigo == "A11", quantile(PU, 0.25), NA))
```

Agrupar por Codigo para cuando calculemos el percentil 25 lo calcule para cada grupo, finalmente con el mutate creamos la variable bajo la condicion que solo lo calcule para los codigos A11 y cuando no sea el caso lo deje como NA

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!